# having a problem in autosearch of textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Iam using autosearch in textbox from database its working good its searching and all the places also changing with the change in that box but problem is that i have a auto generate id box if my autosearch textbox founds nothing then the auto id box should come to its defahult value

```
 Private Sub txtvendorname_frmvdt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtvendorname_frmvdt.TextChanged
        Try

            conn95.Open()
            qryvi = "select * from tblvendorinfo where Vendorname='" & txtvendorname_frmvdt.Text & "'"
            cmdcu = New SqlCommand(qryvi, conn95)
            cmdcu.ExecuteNonQuery()
            drvi = cmdcu.ExecuteReader
            If drvi.Read Then
                txtvendorid_frmvdt.Text = drvi("Vendorid")
                txtvendoraddress_frmvdt.Text = drvi("Vendoraddress")
                txtvendorstate_frmvdt.Text = drvi("Vendorstate")
                txtvendorgst_frmvdt.Text = drvi("Vendorgstno")
            Else
                'txtvendorid_frmvdt.Text = drvi("Vendorid")

                txtvendoraddress_frmvdt.Text = ""
                txtvendorstate_frmvdt.Text = ""
                txtvendorgst_frmvdt.Text = ""



            End If





            conn95.Close()
            Loadvendorid1()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute a query, then calling `ExecuteReader` to execute the same query a second time?

Comment: If there's no match then you have no code that does anything relating to `txtvendorid_frmvdt`, which I assume is the `TextBox` you're talking about. If you expect something to be displayed in that `Textbox`, write code to display it. It's not going to happen on its own. We have no idea what default value you're talking about.

Comment: Usually they expect to find a way to calculate the next id for the table. A very doubtful practice, but I am just guessing

Comment: in vendor id i have given a auto increament alphanumeric id which i need back the next vendor id no when i found nothing in vendor name

Comment: Are you asking for a method to generate a new Alphanumeric vendor id?

Comment: No I have already written the code of auto ID generate ID to box vendorid the problem is if vendor name found nothing then the  code have to generate, because if the user find nothing in database he will try to put new vendor details and how he could find the last vendorid no